# Why google chrome doesnot displaying wordpressblog link page

Tags: css, wordpress

I have already created 5 posts for wordpress blog page and it is working fine in firefox but on google chrome at home page it shows 5 blog posts with heading but on clicking on any one of them they doesnot appear on next tab means the page is blank. Please help...

Comment: Code or does not happen

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens while your site content is showing in firefox bot not in google chrome.

For this you can clear all browser cookies and cache.

shortcut key ==> Ctrl+Alt+Del ==> select all check-box and clear the browsing data from the beginning of time.

Than after reloading your site you can have you site content in Google chrome browser.